# XML/XSLT Output pairs

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can someone please give me some guidance on how to find all pairs of movies starring Johnny Depp that were produced in the same year using XSL 1.0, while making sure that each pair is only outputted once, more specifically, to output only pairs where the second movie @id is larger than the first movie @id, as such:

```
<same_year actor="Johnny Depp">
<pair year="..">
<movie id=".."> ... </movie>
<movie id=".."> ... </movie>
</pair>
...
</same_year>
```

XML:

```
<movie id="475" imdb_id="0107207">
<title>In the Name of the Father</title>
<year>1993</year>
<critic_rating>7.6</critic_rating>
<critic_num_reviews>39</critic_num_reviews>
<critic_score>94</critic_score>
<audience_rating>4.0</audience_rating>
<audience_num_ratings>10715</audience_num_ratings>
<audience_score>92</audience_score>
<directors>
<director>Jim Sheridan</director>
</directors>
<actors>
<actor rank="1">Daniel Day-Lewis</actor>
<actor rank="2">Pete Postlethwaite</actor>
<actor rank="3">Emma Thompson</actor>
<actor rank="4">John Lynch</actor>
...
<actor rank="60">Philip King</actor>
</actors>
<countries>
<country>Ireland</country>
</countries>
</movie>
```

thanks.

Comment: Please share whatever you made till now.

Comment: It may help a bit if your showed an XML sample that actually contained at least one Johnny Depp movie. "In the Name of the Father" is a fine film, but I don't recall seeing Johnny Depp in it! Also, Johnny Depp is quite a hard-working actor, so what would you want to happen if had three movies out in the same year? Thanks!

Comment: You should put the whole thing into a database and query it using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work (untested):

```
<same_year actor="Johnny Depp">
    <xsl:for-each select="movie[actor = 'Johnny Depp']">
        <xsl:variable name="movie1" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../movie[actor = 'Johnny Depp' and year = $movie1/year and @id &gt; $movie1/@id]">
            <pair year="{year}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$movie1"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </pair>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</same_year>
```

There are two `for-each` loops looping over every pair of movies matching the criteria.